# CSS - Printing issue when using print preview

Tags: html, css, printing

I have an issue where a document is printed differently depending on whether `File->Print` or `File->Print Preview->Print` is chosen.

My css file has options set for `@media print` which are obeyed when using the first action. But they seem to be ignored when the second path is used.

My company only supports IE in case that is important.

Has anyone got and solutions?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: IE's support of print CSS is crappy, at best.

Comment: That's really helpful. IE is what's supported and theirs nothing I can do about that.

Comment: an example link to see and try to debug the problem?

Comment: @Littlemad - It's a internal application, so there's no available link sorry.

Comment: @ash and there's nothing you can do about the print css. Sorry. That's how it is. IE 6 and 7 just have major issues with it. Now, you didn't say which version of IE (which would be helpful info) but I assume any company still using inane 'IE Only policies' are also still stuck with IE6 and 7. I've been there myself, so empathize. But sometimes management has to understand the problem is with their policies, not your code.

Comment: But, to maybe fix your immediate problem, have you tried just making a standard LINK with a media="print" to load the CSS? Try that. If that works, you can at least narrow it down to a problem with IE not supporting the @media properly.

Comment: Just a basic page has the same issues, so I'm going to guess it's yet another bug in IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem Internet Explorer is to blame yet again.

Thanks for everyone's responses.